# Single HTML tag remover script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to replace a tag
`<strong> </strong>`
from every HTML file I have on the server with a PHP script.
I tried doing it with batch CMD but it's not working.
And I have also tried Notepad to find and replace.
It's just I have 100+ HTML files.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p old=old string ? set /p new=new string ?

::cycle for every file of specific folder where you have this script
and all html files for /f %%f in ('dir /b /a-d C:\Path\To\Your\Folder 
\*.html') do (

    set str1=%%f
    ::copy to temp file line by line text with replacing of specific tags
    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%%f) do (
        set str=%%a
        set str=!str:%old%=%new%!
        >> tempfileXXX.txt echo !str!
    )
    ::empty the folder from where you copied
    break>%%f

    ::cycle over every line of temp file to copy back to old file
    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (tempfileXXX.txt) do (
        set str=%%a
        >> %%f echo !str!
    )

    ::clear tempfile
    break>tempfileXXX.txt )

::delete temp file del tempfileXXX.txt pause
```

This is not working don't know why.

Comment: edit your file  with notepad++ they have replace feature.

Comment: I cannot see any question in your post! Just saying "it does not work" is not enough! Please learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

How about rather styling the `<strong>` with CSS? It can act like it was `<div>`.

If you insist, the safest way would be to go with some HTML or XML parser, load the DOM, and then dump the DOM. Provided you have XHTML.

If you can afford going with just replacing, download NetBeans, open your project, and run Replace in files...

Comment: Can you tell me how to replace <strong> with <h4> with css?